# Can domains be used in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

We have a development server at dev.example.com that is being indexed by Google. We are using AWS Lightsail to duplicate the development server to our production environment in totality — the same robots.txt file is used on both dev.example.com and example.com.

[Google's robots.txt documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/create-robots-txt#create_rules) doesn't explicitly state whether root domains can be defined. Can I implement domain specific rules to the robots.txt file? For example, is this acceptable:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: https://dev.example.com/

User-agent: *
Allow: https://example.com/

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

To add, this can be resolved through .htaccess rewrite engine — my question is specifically about robots.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't specify domain in `robots.txt`.   `Disallow: https://dev.example.com/` is not valid.  Page 6 of the [robots.txt exclusion standard](https://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) says that a disallow line should contain a "path" as opposed to a full URL including the domain.

Each host name (domain or subdomain) has its **own** `robots.txt` file. So to prevent Googlebot from crawling `http://dev.example.com/` you would need to serve `https://dev.example.com/robots.txt` with the content:

```sh
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

At the same time you would need to serve a different file from `http://example.com/`, perhaps with the content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

If the same code base powers both your dev and production servers, you will need to conditionalize the content of `robots.txt` based on whether it is running in production or not.

Alternately, you could allow Googlebot to crawl both, but include `<link rel=canonical href=...>` tags in every page that point to the URL for the page on the live site.  See [How to use rel='canonical' properly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/848/how-to-use-rel-canonical-properly)

Comment: Can you provide documentation or source on the robots.txt? Canonical is a good solution.

Comment: I edited to add a reference to the spec.  You can also use [Google's robots.txt test tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en) to verify how Google would interpret it if you included the domain name.

Comment: I confirmed `disallow: http://dev.example.com/` and `allow: http://example.com` are ignored entirely

Answer (score 1):

Listing full domains in robots.txt is not allowed according to [Google's Create a robots.txt documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/create-robots-txt?hl=en#:%7E:text=A%20directory%20or%20page%2C%20relative%20to%20the%20root%20domain%2C%20that%20you%20don%27t%20want%20the%20user%20agent%20to%20crawl.):

> "**A directory or page, relative to the root domain**, that you don't
> want the user agent to crawl. If the rule refers to a page, it must be
> the full page name as shown in the browser. **It must start with a /
> character** and if it refers to a directory, it must end with the /
> mark."

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express nodejs, I solved it by checking the request headers host and responding with a disallow robots txt.

```
app.get('/robots.txt', function (req, res) {
  if (req.headers.host === "localhost:8080" ||
    req.headers.host === "algonewbie.fly.dev") {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.send("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /");
  }
});
```